# while loop memory problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

The problem with this code is that when the while loop is executing, the memory usage is increasing continuously. I want to know why does this code keeps on increasing memory when its in while loop.
Which object here is eating the memory. What can i do so that the memory does not increase in the loop.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSNumber *totalTime = [[self nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
while (self.currentPlaybackTime < [totalTime floatValue]) 
{
    NSNumber *currentTime = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.currentPlaybackTime];
    if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])
    {
        [NSThread exit];
        [newThread release];
    }
    else if([totalTime intValue] - [currentTime intValue] == 1.0)  
    {
        if(currentTime)
            [currentTime release];
        break;
    }
    [currentTime release];
}
[pool release]
```

Comment: [pool drain]; use the allocations instrument to find when you get the problem

Comment: As i hv mentioned, the memory increases when while loop is in execution. Is there anything else that i can get from Allocations instrument?

Comment: If you see the WWDC video's of last year you see that they place the autorelease pool in the while. This releases any autorelease object per cycle, making it less of a memory drain.

Comment: placing autorelease pool inside the while loop didn't help. The problem persists.

Comment: You realise that this code is hammering the CPU and emptying the battery without any good reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Replaced the while loop with Timer and made few changes. 
Created a timer which fires every second

```
 timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                target:self
                              selector:@selector(performAction)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:YES];
```

then in performAction, check for the current playback time and invalidate the timer it the difference in time is <= 1 sec

```
int totalTime = [[[self nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] intValue];
    if((totalTime - self.currentPlaybackTime) <= 1.0)
    {
        if(timer)
            [timer invalidate];

         /* Performed my desired action here.... */
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your changes here, in case anyone else runs into the same problem and finds your question on Google?

Comment: It's not really a problem per se - he's running a tight loop that iterates as fast as possible and creates auto-released objects in that loop. The solution is DON"T DO THAT.

Answer (score 0):

That is some inefficient code you have there.... Heres a replacement that doesn't go mental allocating memory for no reason, further more you might want to put a sleep in there so it doesn't eat CPU

```
// not needed any more
//NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int totalTime = [[[self nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] intValue];

while (self.currentPlaybackTime < totalTime) 
{
    //not needed any more
    //NSNumber *currentTime = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.currentPlaybackTime];
    if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])
    {
        [NSThread exit];
        [newThread release];
    }
    else if((totalTime - self.currentPlaybackTime) <= 1.0)  // you may never hit 1
    {
        break;
    }
}
//[pool release]
```

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanx for your code but the problem persists. The memory keeps on mounting when its in the while loop. And yes, after seeing this code, i feel embarrassed about my code.I am still new to iOS and hopefully ill improve my coding style.

Comment: @Dhawal If the memory is still growing, then the problem is probably not in the code you showed us. Or you might have picked up the wrong thing in the Instruments.